# Benchmark Nodejs Project

Tags: performance, node.js, benchmarking

I am trying to build a nodejs web application. As I am adding more code, it would be nice to have a way to test the performance impact of such a change, and if possible what things my app is spending the most time on. I am currently using mocha for my test framework, and I can get some benchmarking information from that, since it reports out how much time each test takes. However, I end up editing the tests occasionally, invalidating all my previous benchmarks.

I was wondering if anybody has any suggestions on nodejs modules or approaches on how to accomplish this.

Comment: Does anyone have any opinion on concurix? http://concurix.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably want to setup tests for just benchmarking the speed and have your unit tests separate.

You could also use a load tester like [Apache Jmeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) or a service like [BlazeMeter](http://blazemeter.com/)

And if you just want really good node compatible benchmarking library, there is [Benchmark.js](http://benchmarkjs.com/)